# Youtube iframe api v3 restrictions

Tags: youtube-api

Is there way to filter search results for videos that can be played from a certain country in youtube iframe api v3?

This call is not working:

```
search.setRegionCode("TR");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a filter for it as of now, but from the videos in the response,

1) Do a videos.list call with id = comma separated list of all videoIds returned in your first call.

2) You can filter them by [contentDetails.regionRestriction](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction)